# how to prvent specific pages from being cached in squid?

Tags: apache-2.2, squid, drupal, curl

I have drupal based website and i am using squid as a caching level.
now, the homepage keeps getting un-updated content (old contents) and by running curl -I on my website i got this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2011 11:52:15 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Mar 2011 17:44:47 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 77428
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Cache: MISS from Servername.MyWebsite.com
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from Servername.MyWebsite.com:80
X-Cache: MISS from Admin
Connection: close
```

although it shows **X-Cache:MISS** in curl but it keeps giving old content.
now the question is: how can i configure squid to NOT cache my homepage or specific pages??
Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't those headers show that Squid is NOT serving cached content. I believe Squid inserts the x-Cache HTTP headers. The others, for example Last-Modified are coming from Apache. I would look elsewhere for the problem - What does your Apache logs say for this request?

Comment: nothing in apache access log !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default squid will not cache non-cacheable content - which this obviously is. If you're getting a cache miss but seeing old content, then you've got more caching happenning deeper in your stack.

Comment: so, what shall i do to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can block a certain file, but you could block a domain.

```
acl no_cache_mydomain dstdomain .mydomain.com
cache deny no_cache_mydomain
```

Comment: the problem is in homepage only, other pages come correctly!! :((